# DEoptim in R returns an error when I use fnMap parameter

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to use DEoptim with fnMap parameter which is as stated in the documentation "an optional function that will be run after each population is created" so I create this simple test case.

```
fnm <- function(x) round(x, 2)
fn <- function (x) x ^ 2

upper <- 100
lower <- -100

DEoptim(fn=fn, lower=lower, upper=upper, fnMap=fnm)
```

The problem is when I use fnMap parameter it returns an error {**mapping function did not return an object with dim NP x length(upper)**} for any kind of map function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expected return is dim NP x length(upper).  You've got `upper` as `length` 1.  You can *try* to set dim NP to 1 using `control`.  For example...

```
DEoptim(fn=fn, lower=lower, upper=upper, fnMap=fnm,control=DEoptim.control(NP=1))
```

but you'll get this warning...

```
Warning in DEoptim(fn = fn, lower = lower, upper = upper, fnMap = fnm, control = DEoptim.control(NP = 1)) :
  'NP' < 4; set to default value 10*length(lower)
```

but this tells us that NP defaults to `10 * length(lower)` which is useful.  You just need to redine your function to

```
fnm <- function(x) matrix(round(x, 2), nrow=10, ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
```

but this assumes you always have a `length` 1 parameter set.  I would probably do something like this

```
fnm <- function(x, Len) matrix(round(x, 2), nrow=10*Len, ncol=Len,byrow=TRUE)
```

and then call DEoptim like this

```
DEoptim(fn=fn, lower=lower, upper=upper, fnMap=function(x) fnm(x,length(upper)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first solution which uses control gives me warning and Error, but the second one worked perfectly. So I choose this as the right answer. thanks again.

Comment: Yeah the first "solution" wasn't meant as a solution just meant to show how I got to the final answer since the docs don't seem to tell you what the default is for NP.